# How to resolve package conflicts installing LibreOffice 3.6.4?

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice, dpkg, 32-bit

The latest release of LibreOffice is 3.6.4, however only 3.6.2 is available in the software centre. I have installed the file available at http://www.libreoffice.org/download/?type=deb-x86&lang=en-GB&version=3.6.4 (And yes I am running 32 bit 12.10) and have completed the installation instructions in the ReadMe file that comes with it up to:

```
cd desktop-integration
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

at which point I received the error:

```
dpkg: regarding libreoffice3.6-debian-menus_3.6.4-3_all.deb containing libreoffice-debian-menus:
 libreoffice-debian-menus conflicts with libreoffice-bundled
  libreoffice-core provides libreoffice-bundled and is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing libreoffice3.6-debian-menus_3.6.4-3_all.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing libreoffice-debian-menus
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libreoffice3.6-debian-menus_3.6.4-3_all.deb
```

After which I performed:

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-bundled
```

And restarted the last command that is:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Which failed this time too.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*`, this will remove all traces of the previous installation of libreoffice. After this you will need to follow the guide again.

Comment: It worked perfectly, if you want some more reputation just write that up as an answer and I'll accept it and give it a vote up too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely there are still traces present from your old libreoffice installation, you can remove these with

```
sudo apt-get purge 'libreoffice*'
```

Then try to follow the guide again.